# Example consistency of functions

Tags: consistency, example

I know that as long as the population moments exist and the data are identically distributed the raw sample moments, the central sample moments and the sample quantiles are consistent. This concept of consistency also carries over to functions of random variables.

[image]

If g is continuous in a and h in (a,b).

Now I am trying to find examples for each of these situations. The standard deviation is absolutely an example of the third bullet point and the Sharpe ratio (mean divided by standard deviation) is a good example of the second bullet point. But I am stuck finding (easy) examples for the first and the fourth bullet point. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, there are many examples you can create from [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_5_convergence_in_probability.php) and subsequent pages.

For the latter, simply take $h$ to be the product i.e. $(x, y) \mapsto xy.$ Clearly, $h$ is [continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1160357/1074816). This is nothing but nodding to the more general result that if $\mu$ is finite, and $f_n\overset{\mu}{\to} f, g_n\overset{\mu}{\to} g$ where all the functions are real-valued and measurable on a domain set, then $f_ng_n\overset{\mu}{\to}fg.$